# Woocommerce Setup not completing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

While trying to install an existing site on my localhost, i am finding this weird error. I can login in the dashboard. After that I can not go to any other links. The woocommerce setup wizard shows always.

I have tried to skip the setup by pressing not now and also tried to setup the woocommerce. But nothing seems to work.

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging in WooCommerce I found the filter `woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard`:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard', function(){return false;},999);
```

Add that line to your (child) theme functions.php

Let me know if it works.

NOTE: this is just a 'patch'. Woocommerce should not behave like this, most likely you will get more errors along the way.

Regards, Bjorn